# Is it Possible to Build a REST API interface on top of the Spark Cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, apache-spark, amazon-emr

Essentially, we are running a batch ML model using a Spark EMR cluster on AWS. There will be several iterations of the model so we want to have some sort of model metadata endpoint on top of the Spark cluster. In this way, other services that rely on the output of the EMR cluster can ping the spark cluster's REST API endpoint and be informed of the latest ML system version it's using. I'm not sure if this is feasible or not.

**Objective:**

We want other services to be able to ping the EMR cluster which runs the latest ML model and obtain the metadata for the model, which includes ML system version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you want to add metadata (e.g., version, last-updated, action performed etc) somewhere once the spark job is finished, right?

There can be several possibilities and all will be somehow integrated into your data pipeline in the same way as other task, for example, triggering spark job with workflow management tool (airflow/luigi), lambda function or even cron.

**Updating meta-data after Spark job runs**

So for the post spark job step, you can have add something in your pipeline that adds this metadata to some DB or event store. I am sharing to options and you can decide which one is more feasible

1. Utilize cloudwatch event and associate a lambda with the event. [Amazon EMR automatically sends events to a CloudWatch event stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-manage-cloudwatch-events.html)
2. Add a step in your workflow management tool (airflow/luigi) that triggers a DB/event-store update step/operator "on-completion" of the EMR step function. (for e.g., using `EmrStepSensor` in Airflow to issue next step of writing to DB depending on that)

**For Rest-api on top of DB/event store**

Now, once you have regular updating mechanism in place for every emr spark step run, you can build normal rest API using `EC2` or a `serverless API using AWS lambda`. You will essentially be returning this meta-data from the rest service.